# Chebyshev's inequality on compact sets

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality

Could anyone just tell me in which context Prof.
Martin Hairer [here](http://www.hairer.org/notes/Markov.pdf) in page $31$ and Theorem $4.21$ has used Chebyshev's inequality to prove a sequence of probability measure is tight?

Roughly: there is a family of compact sets for a Lyapunov function $V$ for a transition probability measure $P$,  $K_c=\{x: V(x) \le c\}$ and he says by

Chebyshev's inequality $\dots$

Could anyone give some reference where I can read a bit that inequality can be applied on some compact sets? Thanks. If one could simplify that line for me, it would be really great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the following inequalities:
\begin{align}
\widetilde{C}&\geqslant V_n=\int V(y)P^n(x,dy)\\
&\geqslant \int \mathbf 1_{\mathcal X\setminus K_c}(y) V(y)P^n(x,dy)\\
&\geqslant c \int \mathbf 1_{\mathcal X\setminus K_c}(y) P^n(x,dy) \quad\mbox{ because } \mathbf 1_{\mathcal X\setminus K_c}(y)V(y)P^n(x,dy)\geqslant c \mathbf 1_{\mathcal X\setminus K_c}(y)\\
& =c\left(1-P^n(x,K_c)\right)\quad\mbox{ because }P^n(x,\mathcal X)=1.
\end{align}